# demostrate Jensen's inequality (i think)

Tags: self-study, estimation

[image: this is my problem]

Please any help is very good. I was trying to start with the definition of expected value but I don't know how to finish.

Comment: Is there a typo in the problem statement? Why is the estimator $\hat\theta_2$ defined but never used?

Comment: I could have sworn that the same question was asked a couple of days ago, and put on hold by @whuber who asked the same question as Blue Marker: Why is the estimator $\hat{\theta}_2$ defined but never used?

Comment: I believe that the statement is wrong ( my english is not very good sorry).  Please dont considere the second estimator. How would you do it just with the first?

Comment: I have marked this as a possible duplicate. It appears there is a typo in the question here, since indeed, the estimator $\theta_2$ is defined but never used.

Comment: @Dilip Good eye!  It was http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116085/probability-problem.  Thank you for identifying the duplicate, Alecos: it makes the nature of the typographical error apparent.